# MYSQL GROUP BY PERFORMANCE

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, group-by, timestamp

I've got a table named **DATA_TIMESLOTS** containing nearly 1,5M rows. 
The table is made in this way:

```
+-------+---------------+-----------+
|   ID  | SRV_TIMESTAMP | DEVICE_ID |
+-------+---------------+-----------+
| 134322|   1414583866  |     A1323 |
| 134323|   1414583832  |     B1423 |
| 134324|   1414583876  |     A1323 |
| 134325|   1414583883  |     B1423 |
| 134326|   1414583896  |     A1323 |
| 134327|   1414583964  |     C1524 |
| 134328|   1414581065  |     A1323 |
| ....  |     ........  |     ..... |
+-------+---------------+-----------+
```

***ID*** is incremental PK, ***SRV_TIMESTAMP*** and ***DEVICE_ID*** forms a Cluster Primary Key (as different device_id might have the same srv_timestamp)
Another table named **DATA_RAW** contains nearly 1,5M rows as well. The table is made in this way:

```
+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| TIMESLOT_ID  | POWER#1 | POWER#2 | POWER#3 | POWER#4 |
+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|        134322|  342532 |  354365 |  643654 |   77687 |
|        134323|  439642 |  269436 |  363466 |   16436 |
|        134324|  436252 |  326436 |  643645 |   31616 |
|        134325|  564326 |  867867 |  176471 |   16466 |
|        134326|  148585 |  643633 |  754277 |   43643 |
|        134327|  345298 |  754765 |  626364 |   32632 |
|        134328|  324898 |  532575 |  634366 |   65436 |
|        ....  |     ..  |      .. |      .. |      .. |
+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Obviously TIMESLOT_ID is the PK for this table.
As you can see TIMESLOT_ID is a foreign key to the first table.
Now I need to obtain statistics per day as follows:

```
SELECT 
T.DEVICE_ID AS DEVICE_ID, 
DAY(T.SRV_TIMESTAMP) AS SRV_DAY, 
MONTH(T.SRV_TIMESTAMP) AS SRV_MONTH, 
YEAR(T.SRV_TIMESTAMP) AS SRV_YEAR, 
SUM(D.POWER#1) AS DAY_POWER#1,
SUM(D.POWER#2) AS DAY_POWER#2,
SUM(D.POWER#3) AS DAY_POWER#3, 
SUM(D.POWER#4) AS DAY_POWER#4 
FROM DATA_RAW AS D 
INNER JOIN DATA_TIMESLOTS AS T ON T.ID=D.TIMESLOT_ID 
GROUP BY 
T.DEVICE_ID, 
YEAR(T.SRV_TIMESTAMP), 
MONTH(T.SRV_TIMESTAMP), 
DAY(T.SRV_TIMESTAMP)
```

The query works fine but it's incredibly slow (about 60 seconds running on 1,5M records on a 64bit 4 CPU / 4GB machine). I suspect that despite I've well placed indexes on **DEVICE_ID**, **SRV_TIMESTAMP** fields in the **DATA_TIMESLOTS** table, those indexes are void because of the **DAY()**,**MONTH()**,**YEAR()** functions. So I've tried to use the **DATE()** function instead, but the result is the same. So the question is: do I have to add additional fields for Day, Month, Year in the **DATA_TIMESLOT** table putting a proper index on them and wasting some space in order to increase performances or there is another way to obtain this result without such a waste of space?

Well I've made some tests on My SQLSERVER Express 2005 (Microsoft) and I've to admit that the above issue is totally solved. It's confirmed that MySQL is unable to preserve keys or index after a function has been applied on a key or index. Quite a serious limitation IMHO.
The solution seems to be:
1) Add 3 additional fields for days, month, year
2) Index those fields
3) make the group by on those fields
On the other side I'm taking seriously the possibility to remove the Timestamp field as is totally useless after that. The lesson I learned is that in MySQL Timestamp type should never be used as key or index as when you apply a function to it such as day, month, hour, year and so on, the index will be voided...

Comment: can you prepare a sqlfiddle of this?

Comment: Requires quite a lot of space to replicate the issue by uploading 1,5Million rows... doesn't make sense.

Comment: it does to see the schema (tables and indexes) obviously it does not make sense to upload all data. also showing the query plan with `explain` would be useful

Answer (score 0):

What does your indexing and explain look like? Consider consolidating the Y/M/D group by into an TO_DAYS call, you are calling three functions on the same column.

Comment: I don't see why I should group something that is already grouped. I haven't found anything about this function TO_DAYS in MySQL. Anyway it seems to be a MySQL issue as the same tables in MSSQL Server works fast. The root cause is that MySQL destroys the index when you make an operation on it. Quite a stupid issue, in fact other databases doesn't suffer this limitation.

Comment: Please, educate yourself on indexing before making such obvious statements. MSSQL does no such thing, its simply adds an index on computed values, something you could easily do yourself, or perhaps with just better design.

Comment: I'm sorry @winmutt. It was not my intention to irritate anyone. I apologize for that. I learned that making a query is pretty easy, making a good query is a completely different stuff. For sure it's a matter of indexing but I'm unable to understand where is my error as the same structure and query on MSSQL doesn't show the same behavior. How can do to avoid that such a function as date() or month() having an indexed field as argument makes the query engine to avoid to use index slowing down the performances? I guess that this issue should be quite common, for sure I failed somewhere...

Comment: Simply precompute those values in separate columns on insert. It will be even more efficient than MSSQL.